# Bootstrap 3 dropdown not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with the new Bootstrap 3 and everything works fine, except dropdowns that I want to create. Please note me if someone knows what I'm doing wrong. Here is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</div>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class="caret"></b></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">StumbleUpon</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle with your `navigation.css` file included?

Comment: @thiagobraga +1..with only bootstrap.css its working fine..check this..http://jsfiddle.net/6YeZZ/

Comment: Exactly. I thought that was an issue from structures of Bootstrap 2 to 3, but the code it's alright. Try to put `navigation.css` after `bootstrap.min.css` and post the code to us. And remember to close your `</html>` to validate.

Comment: navigation.css is actually empty, I have removed it in source code now. Also, I have tried all suggested solutions you gave me. And still not working...

Comment: You didn't include `bootstrap-dropdown.js` include it and should work

Comment: Adam is correct. You didn't included `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`, or only the `bootstrap-dropdown.js`, but jQuery is needed to run.

Comment: The code is now updated according to your suggestions. In Google developer tools says all files are loaded correctly. But I still don't get the result. By the way, I'm testing in Google Chrome(latest version). Is it possible that there is something wrong with browser?

Comment: Put `jquery.js` before `bootstrap.js`. And if possible, move both before of `</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">StumbleUpon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and it works if you include jQuery BEFORE bootstrap.js